# wrong with web view is not loading local html file in android

Tags: android

I try to make activity that load embedded html stored in assest file but it wasn't load can any one help this is the code `public class Webv extends Activity{
WebView webview;

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

     setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
     webview = new WebView(this);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_webv);
     webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.wvVideos);
     webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return false;
            }
        });

     webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
     webview.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
     webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
     webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
     webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
     webview.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
     webview.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled( true );
     PluginState state = WebSettings.PluginState.ON;
     webview.getSettings().setPluginState(state);
     webview.loadData("file:///android_asset/", "text/html", "utf-8");
     webview.invokeZoomPicker();
    // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getIntent().getStringExtra("address"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     webview.loadUrl(getIntent().getStringExtra("namemovies"));
}
```

}

`

Comment: You are trying to load something twice into `WebView` by using `loadData()` and `loadUrl()`.

Comment: And you have set `WebViewClient` too.

Comment: okk delete one of it ??

Comment: You need to read and learn [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html)

Comment: webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/" + getIntent().getStringExtra("namemovies"));